# bluetooth - btusb module remove stops bluetooth service

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, bluetooth

I just faced a strange issue; Every time after suspend the **btusb** module is kicked out the RAM *(for some reason but its OK cause I can reinit it manually)* but as a result the `bluetooth.service` must be restarted to  make bluetooth workable again; So my question is...

Is there a way to make bluetooth service "wait" till btusb module is reinited or similar? *I couldn't find the docs to find out which services are available in the mentioned case? So I do need your advise;*

p.s.

- OS: Linuc Arch x64
- btusb v0.6
- kernel 3.16*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some devices lose firmware on suspend, but btusb does not notice that. For some devices it has been fixed in newer kernels.

The fix is that the module is automatically bumped, like you do manually on resume.

Anyway it is a kernel bug. You can test newer kernels or report it upstream.

A workaround is to make a wake up script that will restart it on resume.

Comment: No, I mean is there some bluetooth service lets say NetworkManager-wait-online.service or similar?